# How do a update a variable used to generate the value inside of a list comprehension?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension

I currently have a loop that looks like this:

```py
payoffs =[[0 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 0]
          [1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]]
n= 30
actions = [0 for _ in range(n)]
for i in range(n):
            actions[i] = some_function(n, cumulative_payouts)
            cumulative_payoffs += payoffs[:, i]
```

Is there a more pythonic way to do this with list comprehensions, that allows you to update cumulative_payoffs alongside the loop?

Comment: Could you include a sample input and a sample output for a given n?

Comment: you should provide code that we can run follow the instruction  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @JasonChia I've added some runnable code, but idea is just that for every element in the list comprehension, you update it with some cumulative variable.

Comment: "I've added some runnable code" => I'm afraid it's not - I can spot at least three issues that will prevent it from running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
actions = []
for payoff in payoffs.T:
    actions.append(self.generate_action(n=n, cumulative_payoffs=cumulative_payoffs))
    cumulative_payoffs += payoff
```

This can be condensed in Python 3.8 using an assignment expression, but readability suffers and I'm not personally a fan:

```
actions = [
    self.generate_action(
        n=n,
        cumulative_payoffs=(cumulative_payoffs := cumulative_payoffs + payoff)
    )
    for payoff in payoffs.T
]
```

There's probably a good numpy way to create an array of `cumulative_payoffs` without a loop, and then a list comprehension becomes simpler.